# Run SPARQL Queries on Drupal Nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, rdf, sparql

Is there a way to run SPARQL queries on the RDF generated for certain type of nodes?
E.g., if I have a content type called People described by the FOAF ontology, can I run SPARQL queries on nodes of type People?

Comment: Are you talking about pulling data from one site to another? Typically, querying with SPARQL requires an endpoint to query against (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL). If you're just looking to query nodes of a certain type on your own site, you can build any sort of query against them using Views (http://drupal.org/project/views). If you are trying to query against a different site, you may need to provide additional information to clarify your question.

Comment: No. Let me give an example for what I was looking for, say, I have nodes of content type called User. The content type has a field called Skill, I would like to run SPARQL query to find Users with some skill.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to query from one site to another (see my comment), you should be able to achieve this using the [SPARQL Views module](http://drupal.org/project/sparql_views). [This recent article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-datasets/) provides excellent reference for using SPARQL together with Views.

Comment: No. Let me give an example for what I was looking for, say, I have nodes of content type called User. The content type has a field called Skill, I would like to run SPARQL query to find Users with some skill.

Answer (score 0):

The RDF in Drupal simply maps the data that is already structured in the Drupal database to RDF terms. It is meant to increase data interoperability between systems, so that you can exchange data between two different sites.

If you are working within one Drupal installation, you should be able to access the data that you need without using RDF.

The query that you are describing sounds like one that could be handled without using SPARQL, and by instead using Views (just a regular, content View), filtering by the skill you want.

Comment: Right, I did implement the query using views. But, I was wondering if there is OWL/RDF reasoner support in Drupal? Or is it RDF in drupal can only be used, as you mentioned above, increase data interoperability between systems? For now, I have exported my node class RDF's to an external reasoner (Jena) .

Comment: Yes, the RDF work in Drupal core is focused on data interoperability between sites. There might be others working on integrating reasoning with contrib modules, but not anything public AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [RDF SPARQL Endpoint module](https://drupal.org/project/sparql_ep), but it is no longer maintained.  However its page suggests that you

> use [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/drupal) with the [RDF Extensions (RDFx)](http://drupal.org/project/rdfx) module and the [SPARQL](http://drupal.org/project/sparql) module, which includes the same functionality.

The RDFx page says that:

> The site RDF data can be made available in a SPARQL endpoint with the [SPARQL](http://drupal.org/project/sparql) module

The "last updated" dates on those page are somewhat old, but the latest development releases of the modules are both in 2013.